# How To write a query for testing the following code that written with eplex Lib in ECLiPSe-CLP

Tags: eclipse-clp

I am new in ECLiPSe and have a follwing problem.
when I write and compile this simple program:

```
---------------------------------
:- lib(eplex).

main1(Cost, Vars) :-
Vars = [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, D3],
Vars :: 0.0..inf,            % variables
A1 + A2 + A3 $= 200,            % demand constraints
B1 + B2 + B3 $= 400,
C1 + C2 + C3 $= 300,
D1 + D2 + D3 $= 100,

A1 + B1 + C1 + D1 $=< 500,        % capacity constraints
A2 + B2 + C2 + D2 $=< 300,
A3 + B3 + C3 + D3 $=< 400,

optimize(min(                % solve
10*A1 + 7*A2 + 11*A3 +
8*B1 + 5*B2 + 10*B3 +
5*C1 + 5*C2 +  8*C3 +
9*D1 + 3*D2 +  7*D3), Cost).
------------------------------
```

I dont know how to test it? or what is simple query for test it?

I will be very glad ,If you guide me .
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two arguments of **`main1`** are both outputs, so you can just provide two variables (upper case names) in your query, for example **`main1(C,Vs)`**. Type this into the query prompt (or the query entry box, if you  are using tkeclipse), then the system will run the code and print the answer bindings:

```
[eclipse 1]: main1(C, Vs).
C = 6600.0
Vs = [100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0, 300.0, 0.0, 300.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0]
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```